# Как отловить момент выхода из системы?

Tags: windows, winapi

Есть приложение, которое исполняется все время и сидит в трэе. Когда пользователь выходит из системы (выключение, перезагрузка и просто выход), нужно сохранить состояние приложения в реестр. Как этот момент (перед выходом) поймать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

каждому приложению перед выходом windows рассылается сообщение WM_QUERYENDSESSION

```
function GetMessage(var Msg: TMsg; Wnd: HWnd; MsgFilterMin, MsgFilterMax: Word): Bool;
```

Считывает сообщение, в pамках диапазона фильтpации, из очеpеди сообщений пpикладной задачи. Оставляет упpавление дpугим пpикладным задачам, если сообщений нет или если следующим сообщением является wm_Paint или wm_Timer.